# How to bind a Crystal Report to a Net class DataSource that itself has a collection as a property?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Say I have the following class:

```
    Public Class Result

    Private _name As String
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _contestants As List(Of String)
    Public Property Contestants As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return _contestants
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            _contestants = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I have managed to set the Databinding to the Result class in the report using the Database wizard. However, I am only able to drag the Name property on the report from the Field Explorer.

How can I incorporate the Contestants property too? I tried making a subreport, but I can't navigate to the Contestants property to set this as its datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to create an instance of your list in the constructor before you can put anything in it?

```
_contestants = New List(Of String)
```

Comment: Of course you have, but you confuse configuring the report with showing actual data in it.

Comment: You're right of course. Could it be that you maybe have to put the Properties in some sort of list or array? It seems to work for one but not for multiple Properties, so maybe you have to create some sort of collection for them. Of course I'm just guessing at this point.